# Formula field displaying an image is not showing

Tags: formula

Here are my dates in the system:

```
Ent__c = 3/23/2016 2:18 PM
Res_Rec__c = 3/23/2016 4:24 PM
Comp_Date__c = 2/15/2016 1:46 PM
Res_Date__c = 3/24/2016 8:18 PM
```

Formula:

```
IF(OR(ISBLANK(Ent__c), NOT(ISBLANK(Res_Rec__c)), NOT(ISBLANK(Comp_Date__c))), null, 
  IF(AND(NOT(ISBLANK(Ent__c)), ISBLANK(Res_Date__c)), IMAGE("/img/func_icons/util/help16.png", "Red"), 
    IF(Res_Date__c > NOW()+(5/1440), IMAGE("/img/msg_icons/confirm16.png", "Green"), 
      IF(Res_Date__c >= NOW(), IMAGE("/img/msg_icons/warning16.png", "Orange"), 
            IF(Res_Date__c < NOW(), IMAGE("/img/msg_icons/error16.png", "Err"), null)
        )
    )
  )
)
```

what is wrong in the above formula why is it not displaying an image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first part of IF says if `Res_Rec__c` or `Comp_Date__c` is not blank then return null.

Since you have values in those fields, its returning null and not getting into the other conditions at all..

believe you want something like if all 3 fields are blank, return null.

if so change your condition to

```
IF(AND(ISBLANK(Ent__c),ISBLANK(Res_Rec__c),ISBLANK(Comp_Date__c)), null, 
  IF(AND(NOT(ISBLANK(Ent__c)), ISBLANK(Res_Date__c)), IMAGE("/img/func_icons/util/help16.png", "Red"), 
    IF(Res_Date__c > NOW()+(5/1440), IMAGE("/img/msg_icons/confirm16.png", "Green"), 
      IF(Res_Date__c >= NOW(), IMAGE("/img/msg_icons/warning16.png", "Orange"), 
            IF(Res_Date__c < NOW(), IMAGE("/img/msg_icons/error16.png", "Err"), null)
        )
    )
  )
)
```